# Kivy: how to reference widgets from python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Basic Kivy question. Given this kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    MainMenu:
    MyCanvasWidget:

<MainMenu>:
    Button:
        on_press: root.do_action()
```

How do I call a method of MyCanvasWidget (for drawing something) from the do_action method when the button in MainMenu is pressed?

Comment: Might want to mention Kivy in the title so people know that's what you're talking about

Comment: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code

Comment: Yeah, but that works in the same class only, right? MainMenu and MyCanvasWidget are different classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
BoxLayout:
    MainMenu:
        do_action: mycanvas.method
    MyCanvasWidget:
        id: mycanvas

<MainMenu>:
    Button:
        on_press: root.do_action()
```

Got some inspiration from [How to access some widget attribute from another widget in Kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807997/how-to-access-some-widget-attribute-from-another-widget-in-kivy?rq=1)